# How to make report based on XML datasource with one-to-many relationships?

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports

I need to write a report with *iReport* from an *XML data source* that has a one-to-many relationship.

My main table is a list of users and each row in this table maps to many rows in the roles table. When I get the information as an XML document, it has the following structure:

```
<results>
  <user>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <id>12345</id>
    <roles>
      <role>
        <name>Reports on Self</name>
        <id>50</id>
      </role>
      <role>
        <name>Reports on Others</name>
        <id>51</id>
      </role>
    </roles>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <id>54321</id>
    <roles>
      <role>
        <name>Reports on Any</name>
        <id>53</id>
      </role>
      <role>
        <name>Changes to Any</name>
        <id>63</id>
      </role>
    </roles>
  </user>
</results>
```

What I need is for the results to display like so.  I've found information on how to do something similar with subqueries, but I am not connecting directly to a database. I need to run the report off the XML document.

```
List of Users:
12345       John Smith
            Roles:
               Reports on Self
               Reports on Others

54321       Jane Doe
            Roles:
               Reports on Any
               Changes to Any
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't have time to give an example but you can use XSLT to convert to HTML which would allow the formatting you need. Here is a reference link: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are aren't going to be able to do what your asking with just XPath, as its only useful for querying elements in XML. But with something like XSLT, this is possible.

Using your file above, with the XSLT below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>List of Users:
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="user">
    <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
    <xsl:text>       </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="roles"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="roles">
    <xsl:text>            Roles:
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="role">
    <xsl:text>               </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... you get the following output:

```
List of Users:
    12345       John Smith
                Roles:
                   Reports on Self
                   Reports on Others
    54321       Jane Doe
                Roles:
                   Reports on Any
                   Changes to Any
```